# MSAL Java web API for DNS and records

Tags: java, azure, dns, azure-ad-msal

How can we create zone DNS and records on Azure server using Azure web services API with latest "MSAL" library not ADAL based? However DNS library support https://github.com/Azure-Samples/dns-java-host-and-manage-your-domains does not mentioned any way to utilized using MSAL access token. For example

```
ApplicationTokenCredentials credentials = new ApplicationTokenCredentials(client, tenant, key, AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
azure = Azure.authenticate(credentials).withSubscription(subscriptionId);
ResourceGroup resourceGroup = azure.resourceGroups().define(rgName)
        .withRegion(Region.US_EAST2)
        .create();

System.out.println("Creating root DNS zone " + customDomainName + "...");
DnsZone rootDnsZone = azure.dnsZones().define(customDomainName)
        .withExistingResourceGroup(resourceGroup)
        .create();
```

But it is using with keys instead of access tokens provided by MSAL. This can be already achieved in old ways which is using ADAL internally by Azure.

Comment: You can use `msal` to get access token then directly call Azure rest API(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/dns/) with the token to manage dns

Comment: Do you have any other concerns? If you have no other concerns, could you please accept it? It may help more people who have similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Azure java management SDK to manage Azure DNS with AD access token, please refer to the following code

a. create a service principal  (I use Azure CLI to do that)

```
az login
az account set --subscription "<your subscription id>"
# the sp will have Azure Contributor role
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "readMetric"
```

[image]

2. Code

```
 public void test() throws MalformedURLException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {



        AzureTokenCredentials tokenCredentials = new AzureTokenCredentials(AzureEnvironment.AZURE,ADProperty.tenantId) {
            @Override
            public String getToken(String resource) throws IOException {
                String token =null;
                // use msal to get Azure AD access token
                ConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplication.builder(
                        ADProperty.clientId,  // sp appid
                        ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(ADProperty.clientKey)) // sp password
                        .authority(ADProperty.authority) // "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + sp tenant id
                        .build();
                ClientCredentialParameters clientCredentialParam = ClientCredentialParameters.builder(
                        Collections.singleton("https://management.azure.com/.default"))
                        .build();
                CompletableFuture<IAuthenticationResult> future = app.acquireToken(clientCredentialParam);
                try {
                    token =future.get().accessToken();

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return  token;
            }
        };


        Azure azure = Azure.authenticate(tokenCredentials)
                .withSubscription(ADProperty.subscriptionId); // sp subscription id
        DnsZone rootDnsZone = azure.dnsZones().define("mydevchat.com")
                .withExistingResourceGroup("jimtest")
                .create();
        System.out.println("create DNSZone " + rootDnsZone.name() + " successfully");
}
```

[image]